# Dynamic allocation of array from loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to allocate the divisor in dynamic array and export it to a function for later use. how can I do it?

```
int n,i;
cout << "enter your number for check: ";
cin >> n;
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    if(n%i == 0)
    {
        cout << i << endl;    //divisor result 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what you mean? Do you want to take the `i` value from an array? What do you mean by `export to a function`?

Comment: Are you asking how to store the `i` values which divide `n` for later use, rather than outputting them directly at the time of discovery? What did you try? Have you seen [`std::vector<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: these i values are the divisor. I want to store these values in dynamic array.

Comment: i want to store all the divisor in dynamic arrays.

Comment: yap. i want store these i values in a dynamic array @Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard dynamic array container from the STL is [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Below is a slightly modified version of your code, which appends each found divisor to a `vector` of `int` called `divisors`, and then outputs them at the end of the program just to prove it's actually stored them.

The output code requires your compiler to support C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    int n,i;
    std::vector<int> divisors;

    std::cout << "enter your number for check: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
            if(n%i == 0)
            {
                    std::cout << i << std::endl;    //divisor result
                    divisors.push_back(i);
            }
    }

    std::cout << "Found " << divisors.size() << " divisor(s):";
    for (auto divisor : divisors)
    {
            std::cout << " " << divisor;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```